# Cytoscape.js Compound node label alignment

Tags: cytoscape.js

The cytoscape.js documentation includes alignment option for nodes, specifically, `text-halign` and `text-valign`. For compound nodes, both option place the label in the correct initial locations, however the text appears to grow in (in my eyes) the wrong directions.

Eg. If the text is aligned left, it apears on the left side of the node, and grows to the left, rather than growing to the right. Similarly if text is aligned right, the text appears on the right side of the compound node, and grows to the right.

**Is there not a way to have the text aligned to the left but grow to the right?**

Examples:

`text-valign: 'top', text-halign: 'left'`

```
this is a label
                ----------------------------
                |                          |
                |                          |
                ----------------------------
```

`text-valign: 'top', text-halign: 'right'`

```
                                            this is a label
                ----------------------------
                |                          |
                |                          |
                ----------------------------
```

`text-valign: 'top', text-halign: 'middle'`

```
                      this is a label
                ----------------------------
                |                          |
                |                          |
                ----------------------------
```

What I want:

```
                this is a label
                ----------------------------
                |                          |
                |                          |
                ----------------------------
```

Comment: You could try the `text-margin-x` property. As you can read [here](https://js.cytoscape.org/#style/labels), this property is used to shift the label along the x-Axis. Therefore, you should be able to calculate the width of the label and shift the label by that amount!

Comment: Thanks Stephan. I had considered that but didn't want to do a fixed amount. I hadn't considered making a loose calculation on the text length for a pixel margin amount. Might get complicated with multi-line labels though. I'll look into this, thanks.

Comment: There is actually a private property in each element containing the labels exact positon and dimension (width, height, x, y). If you `console.log()` a node and navigate to `_private.labelBounds.mainRot`, you can see the labels bounds. Unfortunately, I can't access the value (result is always null), but this might be an interesting approach

Comment: Ah interesting as well, i didn't notice that one before. However this really seems like something achievable with CSS rather than more expensive canvas operations. I wish I knew.